# Only post method have Error "Bad request : 400" on nuxt and .netCore as docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js, asp.net-core

`Thank you for reading this page.

I hope someone's help and teaching.

My frontend screen come out correctly.

```
The Error "Bad request : 400" occur Only post method on nuxt and .netCore as docker container.
```

API Tester is show status `"200" on GET even POST` method.Like below URL.

```
http://localhost:5000/api/kokyakus/→　push "SEND" button.

{
"No": "0",
"Name": "data1",
"Kana": "data1",
"Gender": "women",
"Address": "NewYork",
"Age": "25",
"keyword":"",
},
```

Should I Use "id" instead of "No" in SQL server when especially use POST method?

or

Should I Use "withOrigin" instead of "AnyOrigin" in CORS settings?

Settings of "proxy" in nuxt.config.js is very confuse for me.

but this app is moving GET mothod and PUT and DELETE.

so I tell you "thank you very much" when resolve this confuse error or I can have something help.

or

I ReWrite code many time in frontend and backend.

I expect the move correctry POST method and ADD some string data that is indicate at
input form into MYSQL when build frontend container, use "yarn dev" and click button. `

Comment: How do you think anybody could help you based on the information you are giving? Attach a breakpoint in the backend to the handler of that specific route and step through why it returns a 400 ...

Comment: I'm sorry that my explanation was not enough.the container imege of 'backend' is already configure as image.So I will  try to make other app as image, and only 'backend' app run  on visualsutudio or container with commmand with "docker-compose up -d --build" . 
Even when running in visualstudio or running as a container, the API tester has already successfully linked POST processing with the database and added data. If i could show all code of mine.StackOverFlow had limit of charactor.

Comment: Hi. A common pitfall is forgetting to send the CSRF token when your app expects one. That will result in status 400 on POST requests. Have you looked into that? ASP.NET calls them “AntiForgeryToken”.

Comment: hi,benderboy.  I never looked into CSRF.  I will try to configure “AntiForgeryToken”on backend App by visual studio. I will refer to it. Thank you!

Comment: After all, I solved this error. Someone want to know about this error? Send message to me.